# Haskell noobie : lists in type definitions?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm just starting out with Haskell and I want to define a type like this :

```
data Point = Int | [Int]
```

ie. at any Point I want to store either a single integer or a list of integers. (Ultimately I'm going to store these Points in a list)

For some reason it tells me there's a parse error at the [Int].

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a value constructor for each "option" in your data type, so that you can determine whether you have a single Int or a list of Int. For example:

```
data Point = Single Int | Many [Int]
```

Then you can pattern-match on values of this `Point` type:

```
examine :: Point -> String
examine (Single x) = "One: " ++ show x
examine (Many xs) = "Many: " ++ show xs
```

Your original declaration is illegal because otherwise there would be no way to *use* `Point` values, not knowing what they hold.

Answer (score 6):

A data type definition consists of one or more constructor definitions separated by `|`. A constructor definition is an identifier that starts with a capital letter, followed by zero or more type names.

So `Int` is a valid constructor definition because it's an identifier that starts with a capital letter. However it defines a constructor of zero arguments and is not in any way related to the `Int` type. So that's not what you want. If you want a constructor that contains a value of type `Int`, it should be something like `Single Int`, which would define a constructor named `Single` that takes an `Int`.

`[Int]` is not a valid constructor definition because it doesn't start with an identifier. You probably want something like `Many [Int]`. That would define a constructor named `Many` that takes a list of `Int`s.

Comment: But I thought [] was just syntactic sugar for a list constructor?

Comment: @interstar `data` defines a new data type. You're probably thinking of type *synonyms*.

Comment: @interstar `[]` is the list type. It's not really syntactic sugar because there's no other way to write it. Either way a constructor starts with a constructor name, not a type. That applies to both your constructors (as I explained `Int` also does not do what you want) and really isn't specific to lists at all.